# Rails sandbox console stopped showing feedback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure what happended but I was following Rails Tutorial and when I first issued this command:

> rails console --sandbox

it worked fine and showed me the correct feedback of:

```
Loading development environment in sandbox
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit
```

But when I typed this one it started acting weird, didn't show the whole line that I typed, jumped to the first line and did NOT show me the feedback:

```
user = User.new(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you've missed somewhere closing brackets I think. Try `ctrl+C` to stop this non-finished process and try again.